# Excel: local name of boolean value c#

Tags: c#, excel, localization, boolean

I would like to know how Excel displays names of boolean values. For example if cell A1 contains true, english version of excel shows "TRUE" and polish "PRAWDA". How can I programmatically check how excel displays those values for user?

Comment: No doubt being Microsoft it just uses `ToString()`, difficult to tell without the excel source code

Comment: I just want to mention that you can write `"'TRUE"` (with a single quote in front) and Excel will consider the content as plain text, not changing it to the language specific boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get that information without locally running the application. If there is' I'd like to know how.

Running Excel locally you can get the localized strings with the following code:

```
    using System;
    using MSExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MSExcel.Application excel = null;
        MSExcel.Worksheet sheet = null;
        string localizedFalse;
        string localizedTrue;

        try
        {
            excel = new MSExcel.Application();
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            sheet = (MSExcel.Worksheet)excel.Workbooks.Add(MSExcel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet).Sheets.Add();
            sheet.Cells[1, 1] = false;
            sheet.Cells[1, 2] = true;
            sheet.Columns.AutoFit(); //If the localized string doesn't fit in the default column width, the returned text will be ##########.
            localizedFalse = sheet.Cells[1, 1].Text;
            localizedTrue = sheet.Cells[1, 2].Text;

            Console.WriteLine("Excel localized true: {0} \r\nExcel localized false: {1}", localizedTrue, localizedFalse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sheet != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
            }

            if (excel != null)
            {
                excel.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to do that without writing to worksheet. But this answer is also good, thanks!